# How can I make plasma colorfunction for my density plot

Tags: plotting, color

I want to create a density plot in mathemtica and I want to use "Plasma" colormap which is given here (like Yellow corresponds to 0 and Purple corresponds to 1)

https://image.slidesharecdn.com/iuvsta79-henderson-170521181016/95/digging-into-data-analysis-and-visualisation-in-3d-12-638.jpg?cb=1495390645

Any idea how can I create this in mathematica?

Comment: You can construct arbitrary colour maps with `Blend` (please look it up in the docs).

Comment: Sure but I don't know all the colors in Plasma colormap.